# jQuery .remove() - youtube iframe doesn't get deleted fully in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, iframe, xhtml

I'm deleting element **tr** from this table using jQuery 1.7.1 and it's not working well in Internet Explorer (I have 8.07 but I guess more IE do that - other people have the same thing)

Remove call:

```
$("#tr_video_element_1").remove();
```

When I do it, the screen goes black (seems like it is a youtube iframe background or something - a few days ago there was a part of the site that was a link to one of the youtube videos in ).

The code validates fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sorted_elements.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title> Panel </title>
</head>
<body><table id="editorial_table"><thead><tr>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Youtube video id</th>
                    <th>Video</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>  
         </thead><tbody><tr class="video_tr_element" id="tr_video_element_1"><td><input readonly="readonly" class="position" name="input_position_1" id="input_position_1" size="1" type="text" value="1" /></td><td><input class="yt_link" name="yt_link_position_1" id="yt_link_position_1" type="text" value="cjDyJnzYgpk" />
                   <div style="margin:auto; margin-top:9px; width:70px; ">
                        <a href="#" class="up 1" id="up_pos_1"><img src="img/up_arrow.png" alt="Move object up"  /></a>
                        <a href="#" class="down 1" id="down_pos_1"><img src="img/down_arrow.png" alt="Move object down" /></a>
                  </div>
              </td><td><div class="inline" style="height:186px;width:210px;margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding:0; ">

                        <iframe id="if_pos_1" title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player"
                        width="210" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cjDyJnzYgpk"
                        frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div></td><td><a class="delete 1" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr><tr class="video_tr_element" id="tr_video_element_2"><td><input readonly="readonly" class="position" name="input_position_2" id="input_position_2" size="1" type="text" value="2" /></td><td><input class="yt_link" name="yt_link_position_2" id="yt_link_position_2" type="text" value="cjDyJnzYgpk" />
                   <div style="margin:auto; margin-top:9px; width:70px; ">
                        <a href="#" class="up 2" id="up_pos_2"><img src="img/up_arrow.png" alt="Move object up"  /></a>
                        <a href="#" class="down 2" id="down_pos_2"><img src="img/down_arrow.png" alt="Move object down" /></a>
                  </div>
              </td><td><div class="inline" style="height:186px;width:210px;margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding:0; ">

                        <iframe id="if_pos_2" title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player"
                        width="210" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cjDyJnzYgpk"
                        frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div></td><td><a class="delete 2" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr><tr class="video_tr_element" id="tr_video_element_3"><td><input readonly="readonly" class="position" name="input_position_3" id="input_position_3" size="1" type="text" value="3" /></td><td><input class="yt_link" name="yt_link_position_3" id="yt_link_position_3" type="text" value="NMqLH6_bDNs" />
                   <div style="margin:auto; margin-top:9px; width:70px; ">
                        <a href="#" class="up 3" id="up_pos_3"><img src="img/up_arrow.png" alt="Move object up"  /></a>
                        <a href="#" class="down 3" id="down_pos_3"><img src="img/down_arrow.png" alt="Move object down" /></a>
                  </div>
              </td><td><div class="inline" style="height:186px;width:210px;margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding:0; ">

                        <iframe id="if_pos_3" title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player"
                        width="210" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NMqLH6_bDNs"
                        frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div></td><td><a class="delete 427" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr><tr class="video_tr_element" id="tr_video_element_4"><td><input readonly="readonly" class="position" name="input_position_0" id="input_position_0" size="1" type="text" value="0" /></td><td><input class="yt_link" name="yt_link_position_0" id="yt_link_position_0" type="text" value="" />
                   <div style="margin:auto; margin-top:9px; width:70px; ">
                        <a href="#" class="up 0" id="up_pos_0"><img src="img/up_arrow.png" alt="Move object up"  /></a>
                        <a href="#" class="down 0" id="down_pos_0"><img src="img/down_arrow.png" alt="Move object down" /></a>
                  </div>
              </td><td><div class="inline" style="height:186px;width:210px;margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding:0; ">

                        <iframe id="if_pos_0" title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player"
                        width="210" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
                        frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div></td><td><a class="delete 478" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr><tr class="video_tr_element" id="tr_video_element_5"><td><input readonly="readonly" class="position" name="input_position_4" id="input_position_4" size="1" type="text" value="4" /></td><td><input class="yt_link" name="yt_link_position_4" id="yt_link_position_4" type="text" value="NMqLH6_bDNs" />
                   <div style="margin:auto; margin-top:9px; width:70px; ">
                        <a href="#" class="up 4" id="up_pos_4"><img src="img/up_arrow.png" alt="Move object up"  /></a>
                        <a href="#" class="down 4" id="down_pos_4"><img src="img/down_arrow.png" alt="Move object down" /></a>
                  </div>
              </td><td><div class="inline" style="height:186px;width:210px;margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding:0; ">

                        <iframe id="if_pos_4" title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player"
                        width="210" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NMqLH6_bDNs"
                        frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div></td><td><a class="delete 494" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem recently on Internet Explorer 8.
My work around was to first empty the src attribute of the iframe, and then remove it.

```
$('#iframeID').attr("src", " ");
$('#iframeID').remove();
```

Comment: This did the trick for me too, although I used `$(this).attr('src', '');` but it's effectively the same.
Just as an appendix, it's still an issue in IE9 - surprise, surprise! :)

Comment: While this resolves the symptoms, I'd imagine there's an underlying memory leak that we still haven't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (any version) is well known for handling tables and all operations on then very strangely. Why do you have to remove table row (tr)? Can't you simply put your youtube iframe inside any div and then put it into tr (actually into td contained inside tr)? Then you remove div and leave tr empty. You should get the very same effect, but without any problems, that might be caused by removing table row instead of its contents.